# Sticky Nav collision with Content

Tags: nav, sticky

So The issue has now adapted to the content section not acknowledging the navbar once it is "fixed". You can see this when you scroll down slowly (it skips 2-3 lines of text.) Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```js
function fixNav() {

/* Grab .nav */
var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('nav')[0];

/* Find the initial offsetTop position of .nav */
var banner = document.getElementsByClassName('banner')[0];
var socialLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('sociallinks')[0];
var navStartPosition = banner.offsetHeight + socialLinks.offsetHeight;

/* Check current offsetTop position of .nav */
var navNewPosition = nav.getBoundingClientRect().top;

/* If .nav is at the top of the screen (or above), fix it */
if (navNewPosition < 0) {
nav.classList.add('fixed');
}

/* If .nav is in its normal on-page position (or below), unfix it */
if (window.scrollY <= navStartPosition) {
nav.classList.remove('fixed');  
}

}

/* Run function whenever window scrolls */
window.addEventListener('scroll',fixNav,false);
```

```css
.banner,.sociallinks,.nav,.nav ul
{
 max-width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.nav
{
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; font-weight: 300;
}

html
{
 background: #333;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: 50px;
}

body
{
 margin: 0px auto;
 text-align: center;
}

.banner
{
 width: 700px;
 margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
 padding: 0px;
}

.sociallinks
{
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

.sociallinks ul
{
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding: 0px
}

.sociallinks ul li
{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 10px;
}

.sociallinks ul li img 
{
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}

.nav
{
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 background: #333;
 padding: 1px 0px;
}

.nav ul
{
 width: 100%;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 10px auto;
 padding: 0px;
}

.nav ul li
{
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.nav ul li a
{
 width: 60px;
 border-top-color: silver;
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-top-width: 1px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.nav ul li a:hover:not(.active)
{
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #111;
 border-top-color: #111;
}

.nav ul li a.active
{
 border-top-color: #111;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 0.1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.fixed
{
 background-color: #333;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px 0px;
 width: 100%;
 z-index:0;
}

.content
{
 position: relative;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 color: white;
 width: 960px;
 height: 1500px;
 max-width: 95%;
 max-width: 95%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 0px;
 z-index: -1;
 overflow: hidden;
}

table
{
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
     <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
      <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <title>Broadbent</title>
     </head>
     <script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>
     <body>
      <div class="banner">
       <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/655ab7687250c664674d857632b478fa.png" alt="BROADBENT" width="100%">
      </div>
      <div class="sociallinks">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Broadbent45" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/bef1f025ca882ab5d542b9c72b91a76b.png" alt="Twitter"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/OAB450" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/55b8298090b8cb625f3973117af5ee30.png" alt="YouTube"></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/+OAB450" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/396ee154e38f7fe6b2c5328bb806483e.png" alt="Google+"></a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
       <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">HOME</a></li><li><a href="#">MAPS</a></li><li><a href="#">ESSENTIALS</a></li><li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
       Main Section 1<br>Main Section 2<br>Main Section 3<br>Main Section 4<br>Main Section 5<br>Main Section 6
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Can you not just use CSS position:fixed to accomplish this?

Comment: Agreed with @Evan, this can be done with CSS alone

Comment: No, i'm trying to make it be fixed ONLY when the nav bar hits the top of the page

Comment: Also yes, jquery is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution, just using plain vanilla `javascript` (rather than `jQuery`):

```
function fixNav() {

/* Grab .nav */
var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('nav')[0];

/* Find the initial offsetTop position of .nav */
var banner = document.getElementsByClassName('banner')[0];
var socialLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('sociallinks')[0];
var navStartPosition = banner.offsetHeight + socialLinks.offsetHeight;

/* Check current offsetTop position of .nav */
var navNewPosition = nav.getBoundingClientRect().top;

/* If .nav is at the top of the screen (or above), fix it */
if (navNewPosition < 0) {
nav.classList.add('fixed');
}

/* If .nav is in its normal on-page position (or below), unfix it */
if (window.scrollY <= navStartPosition) {
nav.classList.remove('fixed');  
}

}

/* Run function whenever window scrolls */
window.addEventListener('scroll',fixNav,false);
```

Here is the complete working example:

```js
function fixNav() {

/* Grab .nav */
var nav = document.getElementsByClassName('nav')[0];

/* Find the initial offsetTop position of .nav */
var banner = document.getElementsByClassName('banner')[0];
var socialLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('sociallinks')[0];
var navStartPosition = banner.offsetHeight + socialLinks.offsetHeight;

/* Check current offsetTop position of .nav */
var navNewPosition = nav.getBoundingClientRect().top;

/* If .nav is at the top of the screen (or above), fix it */
if (navNewPosition < 0) {
nav.classList.add('fixed');
}

/* If .nav is in its normal on-page position (or below), unfix it */
if (window.scrollY <= navStartPosition) {
nav.classList.remove('fixed'); 
}

}

/* Run function whenever window scrolls */
window.addEventListener('scroll',fixNav,false);
```

```css
#banner,#sociallinks,.nav,.nav ul
{
 max-width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.nav
{
 font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif; font-weight: 300;
}

html
{
 background: #333;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-size: 50px;
}

body
{
 margin: 0px auto;
 text-align: center;
}

.banner
{
 width: 700px;
 margin: 10px auto 0px auto;
 padding: 0px;
}

.sociallinks
{
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

.sociallinks ul
{
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding: 0px
}

.sociallinks ul li
{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 10px;
}

.sociallinks ul li img 
{
 -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5));
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
}

.nav
{
 z-index: 99;
 width: 960px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 background-color: #333;
}

.nav ul
{
 width: 100%;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 10px auto;
 padding: 0px;
}

.nav ul li
{
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.nav ul li a
{
 width: 160px;
 border-top-color: silver;
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-top-width: 1px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.nav ul li a:hover:not(.active)
{
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #111;
 border-top-color: #111;
}

.nav ul li a.active
{
 border-top-color: #111;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 text-shadow: 0.5px 0.5px 0.1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.fixed
{
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left:-480px;
}


.content
{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
 width: 960px;
 height: 1500px;
 max-width: 90%;
 max-width: 90%;
 margin: 0px auto;
 padding: 0px;
 border: 0px;
}

table
{
 width: 100%;
 color: white;
}
```

```html
  <div id="status"></div>
  <div class="banner">
   <img src="https://i.gyazo.com/655ab7687250c664674d857632b478fa.png" alt="BROADBENT" width="100%">
  </div>
  <div class="sociallinks">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/Broadbent45" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/bef1f025ca882ab5d542b9c72b91a76b.png" alt="Twitter"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/OAB450" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/55b8298090b8cb625f3973117af5ee30.png" alt="YouTube"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/+OAB450" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.gyazo.com/396ee154e38f7fe6b2c5328bb806483e.png" alt="Google+"></a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
   <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">HOME</a></li><li><a href="#">MAPS</a></li><li><a href="#">ESSENTIALS</a></li><li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Okay, so this works although it has 1 issue. As you can see here https://jsbin.com/yowejadujo/1/edit?html,css,js,output when you scroll the main content falls upwards in place to where the nav was previously. Can't seem to fix this with CSS. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ah, yes, I see. It's because with `position:fixed` the `div.nav` is now outside document flow and has an effective in-document height of `0`. What that means is that you need to temporarily add `padding-top` to `<body>` equivalent to the number of vertical pixels you have lost. When `position:fixed` is removed again, you can reduce the `padding-top` on `<body>` back to its normal value.

Comment: Added `content.style.paddingTop = "48px";`. Worked like a charm, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your code:

```
jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
```

Should be

```
jQuery(".nav").addClass("fixed");
```

Notice the missing period in the selector.

Edit:

You also must fix the other references to nav.

Additionally, you are using the class selector for the status div but that has an ID not a class so you must use the # selector:

```
jQuery("#status").html(scrollPos);
```

So in all cases, if your HTML looks like this

```
<div class="class-name"></div>
```

Your jQuery will be

```
jQuery(".class-name");
```

and for an element with an id

```
<div id="element-id"></div>
```

Your jQuery will be

```
jQuery("#element-id");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Do i add it for all classes used?

Comment: Yep, anywhere you are targeting a class with jQuery you need the dot selector.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your markup to your script I see the problem is a few typos. You are telling your script to look for things in the markup that do not exist.

On this line: `var navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;` you are referencing a native "nav" element, when you really want to be referencing a classname of "nav".

Change it to: `var navOffset = $(".nav").offset().top;`

Similarly on this line: `jQuery(".status").html(scrollPos);` you are referencing a classname of "status" when you really want to be referencing an ID instead.

Change it to `("#status").html(scrollPos);`

After that, you also need to update your if/else loop to reference the `.nav` classname instead of the native "nav" element.

Give that a try. I was able to get it working in my bin here: https://jsbin.com/lumabe/edit?html,css,js,output

The devil is in the details when it comes to DOM manipulation with javascript!

Here is the complete, corrected script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var navOffset = jQuery(".nav").offset().top;

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    var scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    jQuery("#status").html(scrollPos);

    if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
        jQuery(".nav").addClass("fixed");
    } else {
        jQuery(".nav").removeClass("fixed");
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Thanks! Your feedback was perfect :) Thanks for helping me understand! :D